# Does $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}r^k}{k(1-s^k)}$, where $0<r<1$ and $0<s<1$, have a closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

It converges by the alternating series test. It's like the Maclaurin series for $\ln{(1+x)}$ except it has $(1-s^k)$ in the denominator. (The question arose from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4495702/398708).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F(r,s)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}r^k}{k(1-s^k)}, \text{where $0<r<1$ and $0<s<1$}$$
Use $\frac{1}{1-s^k}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}s^{kj}$
$$F(r,s)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}\frac{(rs^j)^{k}}{k}.$$
$$\implies \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \log[1+rs^j]=\log[\Pi_{j=0}^{\infty}(1+rs^j)]$$
So finally, we have
$$F(r,s)=\log[(1+r)(1+rs)(1+rs^2)...]=\log \text{q-Pochhammer symbol}(-r,s)_ \infty.$$